# Deny direct access to a file on a webserver using rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

My current setup is a web server and an image server.

I would like to be able to view the images on webpages on my web server. However not allow the images to be directly accessible via direct link.

so if someone goes to http://images.mysite.com/image/image1.jpg they should be not be allowed to view the image.

I've tried with the following. However I can still directly access the file.

```
<rule name="PreventImageHotlinking">
                <match url=".*\.(jpg|pdf)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERRER}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERRER}" pattern="^https://www\.mysite\.com/.*$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERRER}" pattern="^https://mysite\.com/.*$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/null.png" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
  </rules>
```

I feel Like I'm very close but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try http instead of https in your url pattern if your image is located under http.